# Draw a 3x3 grid in Cocoa-Touch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, gridview

I plan on making a main menu for my application which contains 9 square boxes in a 3x3 grid fashion.

I would really appreciate it if you could give me some ideas on how to create this and if applicable some tutorials/source code on how to create this effect.

Comment: xcode is just a (integrated) editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend [AQGridView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView). See the examples, that are included.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook [three20 framework](https://github.com/facebook/three20) offers a great [`TTLauncherView`](http://new.three20.info/article/2010-10-21-Launcher) that mimics the apple springboard:

[image: TTLauncherView]